# Actionscript 3 - Type.<T> syntax

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to use the **Type.<T>** syntax with user defined classes?
For example, let's say I want to create a List class, but I want the user to use it like this:

```
var myList:List.<String> = new List.<String>;
```

or is this syntax exclusively evailable to the Vector class only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org) ... you can compile Haxe to swfs as well, and unlike AS3, it supports generics ...

**edit:** Haxe can target flash10 ... unlike ActionScript 3, Haxe even can use alchemy opcodes: http://haxe.org/api/flash9/memory ... plus the generated bytecode is faster ... actually Haxe is a much better tool to leverage the potentials of the AVM2

Comment: But unfortunately, to my knowledge, the current version of Haxe doesn't compile for Flash Player 10.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment it can only be used by the Vector class. Any other attempted use of the syntax will throw a compiler error.